# Convert UTC datetime in ASP.NET MVC using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have UTC date which is one of the properties of a ASP.NET MVC model.
I want to convert it in local time to display.

I wrote the conversion logic in C#, bit as the code will run on server, it will take the local time on server.
  Hence, I will have to convert it in local time on client side i.e. Javascript.

This is my html

```
<label id="UploadedOn">@item.PublicationDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy,hh:mm: tt")</label>
```

How can i convert this date to local datetime using javascript..

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: http://help.dottoro.com/ljlecttk.php

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript

or 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316656/convert-utc-datetime-to-local-datetime

Answer (score -1):

You can create a static method in a utility class which takes the culture as a parameter.

Invoke that method to fetch the culture specific date

```
public static string FormatDate(string culture)
    {
        string returnDate = string.Empty;

        if (culture == "en-US")
        {
            //format accordingly 
        }
        else if (culture == "en-IN")
        {
            //format accordingly 
        }

        return returnDate;
    }
```