# How to Get user preview time in CRM 2011 from using odata ,Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

when i get date and time from odata query in Javascript web resource , it is get deferent from the value in witch is showing in crm form (DateTime filed)

> 

i used this code to format datetime

```
function formatDate(dt) {
    dt = dt.replace("/Date(", "");
    dt = dt.replace(")/", "");
    var date = new Date(parseInt(dt, 10));
    return date;
}
```

### [image]

http://charithrajapaksha.blogspot.com/2013/05/working-with-date-and-time-values-in.html

### this link show how to solve this problem in C# but i want it using Javascript

How can i solving  this matter

Answer (score 1):

Date Time in CRM is stored in UTC and that is why it's off.  You'll need to convert your Date Time to the Date Time of the user.  Here is how to convert it to the [user's browser time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317810/227436).

I will caution you that ideally you should be looking up the user's actual time zone within CRM, but I'd imagine 95% of the time this should work fine.

Comment: times are not match (what i got and preview time)

Comment: Daryl's answer is correct.  CRM Forms display time converted to whatever time zone you have your own user profile set to.  CRM Stores times in UTC, so of course they wont match unless your local time is UTC.