# How to convert mysql datetime to client datetime?

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

Lets say my server is in one country, and the client is in another, date like:

```
2014/12/24 12:00:00
```

how to convert it to the client-browser time?

Comment: this might answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date('2014/12/24 12:00:00').toLocaleString();
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp