# Does ConvertTimeFromUtc() and ToUniversalTime() handle DST?

Tags: c#, timezone, dst

If daylight saving time is in effect, and a date object has been saved into the database (UTC format) which you retrieve to show it in the view (for example the view in `asp.net-mvc`).

And you do that by using this method:

```
public static DateTime ConvertToLocalTimeFromUtcTime(DateTime utcDate, string timeZoneId)
{
    TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
    DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDate, localZone);

    if (localZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(localTime)) 
        localTime = localTime.AddHours(1); // is this needed !?

    return localTime;
}
```

The question is, does `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc()` handle DST's or do you have to check that yourself and either add or subtract X hour(s) to the date object?

Same question for when persisting a date object to the database by converting it to UTC format with `ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: Your timezone is probably using DST right now, which will make your testing really easy to do ;)

Comment: Yes.  Whether DST is in effect in a particular locale is a local political decision.  Not one you ever know enough about on a web server.  Always make the conversion in the browser, it knows.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, true, and I did saw 2 hours being subtracted from the time given from the client. But how about vice versa? Are you saying that I don't have to convert the time in the zone the user is in on server side?

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: [Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript).

Comment: @HansPassant - Converting in the browser is not necessarily the best idea.  It's one approach, but [it suffers from errors](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/).  If you have the time zone id (which the OP does in this case), then `TimeZoneInfo` is going to be more accurate than JavaScript.  Besides, there are plenty of cases where you may want to convert to a *different* time zone, not just the local time zone of the browser.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.  `ConvertTimeFromUtc` will automatically handle daylight saving time adjustments, as long as the time zone that you are targeting uses daylight saving time.

From [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx):

> When performing the conversion, the `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method applies any adjustment rules in effect in the `destinationTimeZone` time zone.

You should *not* try to add an additional hour in your conversion.  That will give you an incorrect translation.

Regarding `DateTime.ToUniversalTime`, it does take DST into account, but be careful with this method.  It assumes that the input value is in the computer's *local* time zone.  If you just need to mark it with `DateTimeKind.Utc`, then use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` instead.