# Can I rely on TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc() in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have to support opening hours in offices around the world. I'm trying to figure it out how to solve problem with Daylight Saving Time. I have checked and `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc()` looks ok. I use it like : `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time"))`. And it seems that I do not have to wonder about the DST, because that method returns correct time. But I wonder if it is that simple or there is trick in it or there is better solution?

p.s. I use .Net 4.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158015/does-converttimefromutc-and-touniversaltime-handle-dst

Comment: You may also be interested in reading [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and [the dst tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).