# JSON to javascript Date.UTC

Tags: javascript, python, json, highcharts

I have the following JSON:

```
[
    [
        "26-Sep-14",
        10
    ],
    [
        "29-Sep-14",
        75
    ]
]
```

The data from the JSON is used to create a highcharts chart, which needs dates in the format Date.UTC(). Currently highcharts is treating the dates as strings. Is there a way to go through the json to format every date correctly (Date.UTC)?

The json originally comes from a Pandas dataframe so perhaps it would be better to make the changes in python before creating the JSON? However I haven't had any luck getting it work in either javascript or python.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/6525602/20126 ?

Comment: You need to get a json in javascript and then parse it, transforming dates into timestamp by Date.parse() or Date.UTC()

Answer (score -1):

Loop through your python panda data object, and for each date, use the python datetime module to convert it to the necessary format using [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

Comment: And how do you do that? Please don't tell users to RTFM... `strftime` has a ton of options.