# DateTime from UTC in Local Time format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a `Date Time` which is saved on the server in `UTC` format.

The date is returned to the client looks like this: `2015-02-05T07:52:27.59`

I need a javascript function which parses the date string, and converts it to the `local time` of the client.

Example, the javascript should add 2 hours to specified time, because the client is on on UTC +2.

I have tried many examples on the internet but non of them was working.

I expect to be something easy, considering that this is happening all over the internet.

Comment: There is no 'localUTC'. UTC is the same everywhere. You need locale time

Comment: Sorry, by bad. I get very confused with date times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string, zero reference the month, use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) when creating the new [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. The output `toString` is local time unless you specify something else.

```js
var dateTime = '2015-02-05T07:52:27.59',
    parts = dateTime.split(/[-T:\.]/g);

parts[1] -= 1;
document.body.textContent = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(null, parts)).toString();
```

Alternatively, if you have a modern browser. Append `Z` to the string and rely on the `Date` parse of the particular browser.

```js
var dateTime = '2015-02-05T07:52:27.59Z';

document.body.textContent = new Date(dateTime).toString();
```

Comment: Exactly what i was hoping for

Answer (score 0):

Just append 'UTC' to the string:

```
var date = new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');
date.toString() // "Wed Jun 29 2011 09:52:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

[Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)

Comment: The date format i have is not valid if i add 'UTC' at the end `new Date("2015-02-05T07:52:27.59 UTC")` is invalid

Comment: How do you create the Date Time object?

Comment: I'm thinking that the toString() method automatically convert it, because I alerted the date and I get GMT + 1 (instead of GMT, which equals to UTC)

Comment: Seems that .toString() automatically converts it if it contains the magical "Z"

Comment: For me it alerts `Thu Feb 05 2015 07:52:27 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time` while it should be 09:52:27 o'clock

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70292/discussion-between-phate01-and-raraitul).