# Display Local Date/Time in ASP.NET MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. This app uses Razor as the view engine. I need to display a date/time to the user. My challenge is, the `DateTime` property on the model is in UTC time. I want to display the time as the user's local time. Currently, I have the following:

```
<div>
@if (Model.LastModifiedOnUTC.HasValue) {
  Html.Raw(Model.LastModifiedOnUTC.ToString());
}
else {
  <span>This record has not been updated</span>
}
</div>
```

I want to display the `DateTime` as something like "Wednesday, February 11, 2015 at 3:27 PM". However, I'm not sure how to do this. When I do the above, an empty string is printed. Which doesn't make any sense to me.

Thank you for any insights

Comment: I believe that this is best done on the client side because the local time zone is known there. So you need to use JavaScript and how is explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript

Comment: Rick Strahl recently did a blog post about this very topic. One of the items in his post talked about capturing the user's default time zone from the browser and doing the calculation of the correct time server-side. Check out his post at http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Feb/10/Back-to-Basics-UTC-and-TimeZones-in-NET-Web-Apps. Scroll down to the section on "Capturing a Web User’s Default Time Zone"

Comment: Can you unaccept the accepted answer? this is not the correct way to do it because it will retrieve the Servers local time, not the Clients. this can throw off a lot of people.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

You can use use following code in razor

```
<div>
@if (Model.LastModifiedOnUTC.HasValue) {
Html.Raw(Model.LastModifiedOnUTC.ToLocalTime().ToString());
}
else {
<span>This record has not been updated</span>
}
</div>
```

Comment: After deployment of the web site, this ToLocalTime() converts the UTC time to the server time zome and not as per the client browser.

Answer (score 14):

One option is to use JavaScript.

in your View

```
<time>@Model.LastModifiedOnUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)<time>
```

JS (my example with JQuery)

```
$("time").each(function (elem) {
        var utctimeval = $(this).html();
        var date = new Date(utctimeval);
        $(this).html(date.toLocaleString());
})
```

Comment: This code is sensitive to servers culture, sinc the ":" colons could end up as dots. Se [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb926074-d593-4e0b-8754-7026acc607ec/datetime-tostring-colon-replaced-with-period?forum=csharpgeneral).

Use instead:
<time>@Model.LastModifiedOnUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)<time>

I just had this problem and corrected it with InvariantCultre.