# Display current datetime depending on client

Tags: c#, azure, timezone, cultureinfo

I am currently saving the datetime.utcnow in the database on azure but im not sure how to display the correct time depending on the client.
Should I be using utc?
Should I save the timezone so I can recalculate the time?
Can I use the culture to change the time to the client time?

Comment: You can use one of these by setting the preference of user in his/her profile. Use that set preference for showing date.

Comment: @imGreg Please, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to store the DateTime as **UTC time** and adjust it to local time (for the user's current location) each time you read it from the database.

You can use JavaScript to determine the timezone of the user:

`new Date().gettimezoneOffset()`

Comment: do i need the offset of saved time in the db?

Comment: No there is no need for it. Just store it like this. DateTime serverDateTime = DateTime.Now; DateTime dbDateTime = serverDateTime.ToUniversalTime();