# JQuery Comparing time in json file with current time

Tags: jquery, json, time, compare

I have json file that is of that format. in Php i created variable that writes time in this format date(h:i:s) to file everytime its being overwritten.

```
{"Time":"11:01:57","Temperature":"21.00","Temperature2":"69.80","Humidity":"49.00"}
```

In client side I want using jquery compare this time from file wtih current time. For example if the difference is lets say 5 minutes then execute something. I dont know how to aproach this

Comment: it will be better if you get complete date including day and year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption:

1. Only time matters and date does not.
2. Also Timezone are the
   same.

   ```
   var startTime = Date.parse('11:01:57'); //Get today date and set time to this
   var now = new Date; //Get today date 
   var difference = (now - startTime); //Calculate difference in milliseconds
   ```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuURb/155/)

Comment: thanks for your response. Could tell me if lets size timezones matters, how would i approach this?

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript