# parse.com, wrong created at field time

Tags: parse-platform

I have searched Parse blog to see if I can get the solution to this, but didn't get any satisfactory answer. So I though I will clearly ask the question here with all the details so anyone else stuck at similar situation will find it easy to work.

actually when a new object is stored in parse.com the created At field display right date year but wrong time. for example. i stored a object at 1 July 2:00 pm , the parse created At field shows July 01 2015 , 08:00... please

i know that we cannot change the value of created at manua**strong text**lly. i tried everywhere please friends help me -

help me

Answer (score 0):

The timezone is different, thats it, See this reference.

https://www.parse.com/questions/timezone-for-pfobjects

You may need to convert time to local time. 
[Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)