# Convert UTC DateTime from server to Local DateTime on web page

Tags: javascript, .net, datetime, razor, utc

I have a `DateTime` column field in `Sql` which is storing Values as `UTC`. Now I have a requirement where in my reports I have to convert the `UTC` into `Local Time` as per the geographical location from where User is accessing the report.

Now I know that `ToLocalTime()` will convert it into required but at the same time it will convert to the place where application is deployed i.e Server not the User's Geo location .

Here is my code snippet ..

```
<td>@string.Format("{0:yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss}", user.StatusDateTime.ToLocalTime())</td>
```

I am using `Razor` View and `javascript`/`jquery` in User interface.
What would be the possible solution ?

Comment: What have you tried and in which of the languages that you have tagged the question in?

Comment: @Xotic750 The Datetime needs to be displayed into jquery Datatable.And as i am using Razor , so inside <td> , used the ToLocalTime() snippet , Pls see the updated post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript

Comment: @ArghyaC Okay.I know How to convert To Local Time in Javascript but here the Page is Razor , and i am directly getting the values from Server into datatable column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, what you can do is, pass the date to the view (without `.ToLocalTime()`), and then use JavaScript to render local date as shown in the link.

```
<script>document.write(new Date('@user.StatusDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss UTC")').toString());</script>
```

Notice the `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss UTC")` to satisfy JavaScript (I guess there are better ways).

**Edit**

If you want to show the date in some specific format (e.g. *2015-Dec-22 12:11:38*), you can use a custom `JavaScript` function. Here is an example.

```
function getFormattedLocalDate(utcDateString) {
    var date = new Date(utcDateString);
    var months = [
      "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
    var formattedDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + months[date.getMonth()] + '-' + date.getDate() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
    return formattedDate;
}
```

See it **[live](https://jsfiddle.net/5wj1qhpw/6/)**.

**Edit 2**

Sample use inside html table [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bxk985u9/2/).

Comment: So this javascript code will convert the Server UTC datetime into User's geo location datetime ?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! for the solution ..I am getting DateTime values as `Tue Dec 22 2015 12:11:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` ..How can i get it like `2015-Dec-22 12:11:38` format..

Comment: Okay i added the function and now trying to add the code in my table as ` <td>
                            <script>document.write(getFormattedLocalDate(new Date('@user.StatusEffectiveDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss UTC")').toString()));</script>
                        </td>` but getting empty value..Why ?

Comment: Write your code as `<td><script>document.write(getFormattedLocalDate('@user.StatusEffectiveDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss UTC")'));</script></td>`, notice the function takes a string, not date object. Also, make sure the function is loaded before this section of html.