# What is the source date of new Date() in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm currently working on a react native project to get the user timezone, I'm using `new Date()` to get the timezone because it's returning :

> Wed Jul 15 2020 17:37:12 GMT+0700

so i can split the result and get the GMT+0700 only. But when i'm trying to change my phone timezone to GMT+0800 in Date & Time setting, the `new Date()` seems not affected and still return GMT+0700. Did anyone know where the `new Date()` get it's date from?

**Update :**

I just found out that enabling `Debug Remote JS` is causing this problem. So what Stark Jeon mention on answer below is correct that React Native got it's `new Date()` from device-info, and why it's not changing is because i'm enabling `Debug Remote JS` and i think the app will get the `new Date()` from the metro js server if you enable `Debug Remote JS`.

Comment: Did you completely terminate the app and run it from scratch when you changed your phone's timezone? Also, did that change stick? You may have your phone set to get that information from the cell signal.

Comment: Maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-offset-in-javascript) then reinstall your app and restart the device.

Comment: i already reinstall & restart my device, but still no luck. The device time is changed to GMT+0800, but the app time still not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm googling for you.
How about checking this question and answer.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552973/get-the-time-zone-with-react-native)

The way I see it use `react-native-device-info` for getting device setting timezone

Comment: thanks for googling for me, I already try that solution yesterday. Right now i want to know why the app time is not the same as device time, even after changing the device timezone