# axios post request in react native and react app with JSON Stringify and blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, axios

I am making an app in which I am calling an API end point in react native but I am getting this error but in the web app (its done with react) it doesn't show any error, Here is the web app code in react with typescript

```
 try {
        let result: any;
        const criteriaWithNoFile = {
            content: filterCriteria.content ? filterCriteria.content.trim() : '',
            filterLimit: filterCriteria.filterLimit,
            sorting: filterCriteria.sorting,
            contractionOption: filterCriteria.contractionOption,
            contentId: filterCriteria.contentId,
            url: filterCriteria.url ? filterCriteria.url.trim() : ''
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUserToken')) {
            dispatch({
                type: LOADER,
                payload: true
            });

            const formData = new FormData();
            const jsonFilterCriteria = JSON.stringify(criteriaWithNoFile);
            const blobFilterCriteria = new Blob([jsonFilterCriteria], {
                type: 'application/json'
            });
            formData.append("filterData", blobFilterCriteria);
            formData.append("filterFile", filterCriteria.selectedFile);
            console.log('FormData', formData);
            try {
                result = await authAxios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/filter`, formData, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed'
                    }
                });
```

and here is the code I am trying in react native

```
const filterData = {
  content: '',
  filterLimit: 1000,
  sorting: 'NATURAL',
  contractionOption: 'LEAVE_CONTRACTION',
  contentId: '',
  url:
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552973/get-the-time-zone-with-react-native',
};
const data = new FormData();
const jsonFilter = JSON.stringify(filterData);
const blobFilter = new Blob([jsonFilter], {
  type: 'application/json',
});
data.append('filterData', jsonFilter);
data.append('filterFile', selectedFile);
await axios
  .post('https://capi.beebl.io/filter', data , {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed',
    },
  })
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong....

Comment: first of all what is the error you got

Comment: request failed with status code 500

Comment: and when I pass the JSON object to axios it gives me status code 415

Comment: try to go debug mode and check network tab and check what error u got from the backend. This is not localhost right =?

Comment: The web app is live that doesn't show any error but I am running the mobile app on my computer I think its on local host..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making a separate API for FileUpload and FilterData