# Django - Return months and years that posts by a user spans given time offset from UTC

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a social media app and I want user A to be able to get all the months with the year that user B posted in user A's time zone. The front-end is in Javascript the most sensible thing would be for a user to send their time zone's offset from UTC (Can be done with `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` in JS, so if you're on EET (Eastern European Time) this would return -120 as EET is 120 minutes ahead of UTC) as this is what time zone dates are saved in Django. So for example user A would ping a url that looks something like `/<user B's username>/<user A's time zone offset from UTC>`.

Let's say user B is in PST and created a post at November 15 2021 12:00pm and December 31 2021 at 11:00pm. Then let's say user A who's in EST calls that url with `/<user B username>/<new Date().getTimezoneOffset() in JS>` then it should return [(November, 2021), (January, 2022)] (Or the equivalent numerical mapping), because December 31 at 11:00pm PST is January 1st at 2:00am EST.

**How can I return all months with year user B posted in user A's time zone, give user A's time zone offset from UTC?**

`models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=POST_MAX_LEN, validators=[MinLengthValidator(POST_MIN_LEN)])
```

Comment: Must it be returned by Django in such matter? I'd recommend just returning the DateTime information as stored in the database and doing the timezone based calculations in JavaScript, or storing user A's timezone in his account and add the difference before returning the result. I don't think an extra endpoint for the offset is the best solution.

Comment: well it gets tricky. If you return all November posts created in UTC when converted some but be in another month.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable time zone support in Django (see [Django Time zones documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/)), you can make queries using time zone-aware datetime objects.

To enable it, you need to set `USE_TZ = True` in your settings file.

You need to [call the `timezone.activate` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) to set the current user's timezone.

Let's assume you're going to send the UTC offset in the URL as above (`/<user B username>/<new Date().getTimezoneOffset() in JS>`) and that you'll have the offset available in a variable called `utc_offset`. You can then set the "current time zone" (i.e. the current user's timezone) like this:

```py
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.activate(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=utc_offset)))
```

Now, when you run `timezone.now()`, the date will be returned in the user's timezone.

And when you render any `DateTimeField` values in any templates, they will be rendered in the user's timezone.

If you're using Django Rest Framework (DRF), [`DateTimeField`s](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) will also be returned in the user's timezone.

If you're not using DRF or rendering the dates in templates, you could get a datetime value in the user's timezone using `astimezone` and `timezone.get_current_timezone()`:

```py
post.created.astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone())
```

### Making queries

If you set `USE_TZ = True` and filter a model using a timezone-naive `datetime`, e.g. `datetime(2021, 1, 10)`, Django will [do the query](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0ed2919814c80e31626dffdb6b80d0c20d43452f/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1411) in the user's timezone.

Comment: yea I think this could work. So once you change timezone to the given offset do you just run a standard query on the `Post` table for all posts created in month X, year Y? Does the timezone shift get applied to the postgresql table? I'm not sure if that's what you meant when you said "And when you render any DateTimeField values in any templates, they will be rendered in the user's timezone."

Comment: Yeah, you just run a standard query, but how the date will be displayed depends on how you render it. How do you return the date values? Do you use Django templates or Django Rest Framework or some other way? The shift doesn't happen in Postgres, it it something that gets applied to the Python representation of the date.

Comment: I used DRF. Let me play with it and get back to you. Your answer is still lacking querying for a month and year in `Post`.

Comment: I don't see you asking about that in your question.

Comment: Isn't that part of the example?

"Let's say user B is in PST and created a post at November 15 2021 12:00pm and December 31 2021 at 11:00pm. Then let's say user A who's in EST calls that url with /<user B username>/<new Date().getTimezoneOffset() in JS> then it should return [(November, 2021), (January, 2022)] (Or the equivalent numerical mapping), because December 31 at 11:00pm PST is January 1st at 2:00am EST."

wouldn't this require a query on `Post` to get all posts in that date range?

Comment: @user8714896 you can filter by timezone-naive dates as usual and Django will [convert](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0ed2919814c80e31626dffdb6b80d0c20d43452f/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1411) the date in the background to the user's timezone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get the problems with users B timezone and server timezone!
As you said,

> Let's say user B is in PST and created a post at.. and December 31
> 2021 at 11:00pm.

it depends on your server’s timezone, how it will be recorded in your database! If you servers timezone is UTC, you’ll have a record: 2021-01-01 07:00. What date is it really was, huh? OK, lets guess you have the servers’s timezone in UTC and in DB there will be record that matches 2021-01-01 07:00.
So, all you need in this case is to add offset to datetime and get the month, like this:

```
def get_month_from_user_side(dt: datetime, offset: int) -> str:
    result_dt = dt - timedelta(minutes=offset)
    return result_dt.strftime('%B, %Y')
```

I have tested it:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_b_post_dt = datetime(2022, 1, 1, 7, 00) # This time – from DB
    offset = -120 # This should be got from JS from user A
    print(
        get_month_from_user_side(user_b_post_dt, offset)
    )

>>January, 2022
```

The “Magic” here is that if user B will ask for his own posts, he will get December just like it should be!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_b_post_dt = datetime(2022, 1, 1, 7, 00) # This time – from DB
    offset = 480 # PST time offset from UTC (for user B)
    print(
        get_month_from_user_side(user_b_post_dt, offset)
    )

>>December, 2021
```

Note: This code needs tests to define the sign of +- timedelta, there can be mistake.

Django's guids recommneds to use set USE_TZ=True https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#setup so I do. I also recommends to set TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you need to do is user data storage through datetime(). The best way I have found to accomplish the same problem is to store every user's timezone and reject any duplicated. Then when any user posts data it records every time zones date and time at that moment and saves it with the post. Then when displaying data you detect what timezone the user is in and display that specific timezones date and time from the post that is being displayed.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to write a query to select objects with a specific timezone. So if you want to do such a query, you either query all posts in that year and then filter the queryset with pure python methods (e.g. `filter()`); either you add a new field to the post where you save the timezone so you can write your query. This would be a more efficient solution.

Still, I would like to point out that such a query is a bit odd, as any datetime is pointing to an exact moment in time and it looks like you're not interested in a time-range, but only the timezone... Maybe the location is what you're after, or a larger area at least.