# React Native device datetime info

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to retrieve information about the datetime settings configured on the client device? For instance, can we determine whether the datetime is set to Automatic or User-defined?

I attempted to obtain information about the datetime settings on the device using libraries such as "react-native-device-info," but there is not information related to the datetime configuration.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552973/get-the-time-zone-with-react-native   for ideas to get the devices settings

Answer (score 0):

You can access the device's native time and date information using the built-in `Date` object.

Here is an example.

```
const deviceDateTime = new Date()
console.log(deviceDateTime)
```

After getting the date and time, hopefully, you'll need to format the date and time.

You can format the date and time like this:

```
const formattedDate = deviceDateTime.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') 
const formattedTime = deviceDateTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')
```

For more, you can follow mdn docs.  [Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)