# How to convert Pacific time (may be PST or PDT) to UTC time

Tags: javascript

I have a Pacific time, e.g. `2016-09-09 01:57:42`. To convert it to UTC time I used

```
d = new Date('2016-09-09T01:57:42-0700')
```

But the problem is for PDT I have to use `-0800`. So how can the Pacific time (may be `-0700` or `-0800`) be smartly converted to UTC time?

Answer (score 0):

Date/time is a nightmare.  Use an existing library that does this for you.  [Moment.js Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) is a popular choice.

```
var d = moment('2016-09-09T01:57:42-0700').tz('UTC');
```

Comment: One of the few places where "use a library, don't do this yourself" is the correct answer. @whjm - The rules are complex and have changed over time. Don't roll your own.

Comment: See this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046067/typeerror-moment-tz-is-not-a-function) for how to include moment in react.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert your PST timezone to UTC than you can use following code :

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-09-09 01:57:42');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo "The UTC is " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br>";
```

You can see list of supported timezones here by PHP :

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Let me know if it is work or not ?

Comment: For eg. `2016-09-09 01:57:42` If this is pacific time than it will work.

Comment: How can it work since you did not provide it with any information about the timezone?

Comment: It will consider as you are passing UTC time. If you are not having UTC time than you should first convert it.

Comment: But it does not know what timezone the time `2016-09-09 01:57:42` is in. That's to say how do you tell it the time is *Pacific time*?

Comment: If you are using JavaScript than you should visit this link : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript