# Converting UTC to local time doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

My datetimes are stored in the DB as UTC. When they are sent to the client I want to convert them to local time.

Javascript receives a given datetime as a string that looks like this:

`2016-09-29T19:13:40`

If I run `new Date('2016-09-29T19:13:40')` on the string I get this output:

`Thu Sep 29 2016 19:13:40 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

While the -0400 offset is present, it's not changing the time. Since UTC offsets aren't displayed to the user, it just looks like the timestamp is off by 4 hours.

Conversely if I do this:
`new Date('2016-09-29T19:13:40').toISOString();`

The output is:

`2016-09-29T23:13:40.000Z`

As you can see it actually adjusts the hours by 4 and eliminates the offset.

How come when I feed javascript a UTC datetime to convert to local all it does is add an offset, but when I feed it what it thinks is a local datetime it and ask it to convert to UTC it actually adjusts the time?

How can I get it to adjust a UTC datetime to local the way it adjusts local to UTC?

EDIT

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjmfLu67/1/

I'm getting different behavior between IE11 and Chrome. IE11 doesn't convert UTC to local. Chrome does convert UTC to local and if it recognizes a date as UTC, when you run `toISOString` on it, it doesn't adjust anything.

Comment: Can't reproduce, I'm `GMT+0200` and it changes the date just fine for me, ending up with `21:13:40` etc.

Comment: Running it on my console I get this: `new Date('2016-09-29T19:13:40')
Thu Sep 29 2016 16:13:40 GMT-0300 (E. South America Standard Time)`

Comment: Needs more context -- are you trying to run this in your browser? Also your "converse" example is actually just making the same assumptions as your initial statement.

Comment: I also can't reproduce and is working fine for me. I am at PST (-0700), and here's what my Chrome console shows: new Date('2016-09-29T19:13:40') >> Thu Sep 29 2016 12:13:40 GMT-0700 (PDT)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)

Comment: @gil.neo I added a fiddle. It seems to behave differently between IE11 and Chrome.

Comment: @MichaelNakayama Yes, it's in the browser. Originally IE11, but I'm testing in Chrome and getting different behavior.

Comment: you're right, I see the issue in IE11 ... makes me hate IE even more  :-P

Comment: @Legion my solution is to not use IE. My other solution is to use moment js like suggested below.

Comment: @MichaelNakayama I'd love to drop IE support. Unfortunately this is an intranet application and IE support is required. I'm currently testing moment js to see if I can use it to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Working with date is not easy, especially if you do TZ conversions. I'd suggest to use momentjs (http://momentjs.com/docs/) for it, like I do.

```
// create a utc-zone moment
var x = moment.utc('2016-09-29T19:13:40')

x.format()
// output is "2016-09-29T19:13:40Z"

// adjust offset for the initial moment x by the local offset we get from moment created against local tz
x.utcOffset(moment().utcOffset());

x.format()
// output is "2016-09-29T22:13:40+03:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for IE11, you'll have to pass the date string in full javascript format for it to work properly.

```
new Date("Thu Sep 29 2015 19:13 GMT")
```

Answer (score 0):

new Date('2016-09-29T19:13:40')

This is missing milliseconds and "Z" which are needed for a correct conversion from UTC to Local.

new Date('2016-09-29T19:13:40.000Z') should give you the correct time relative to your machine.