# jQuery Get linux server time

Tags: jquery

I want to get linux server time in jQuery. But I am able to get server time in GMT but the actual time on server is in EET(European). So now how do I get EET time from GMT. Whether to use **EET=GMT+2h or EET=GMT+3h** on base of daylight time.

Comment: Can you share your code to get the server time? If you know the timezone of the server, you can apply the translation. If you don't I doubt you can get it (unless you create a service which provides the server time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)

Comment: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-126879.html here is how i am getting server time. but its gmt time. and i dont know how to get timezone of server

Answer (score 0):

The only way is using AJAX call to server in jquery. I could not find any way. But ajax method worked for me