# Change date format to client date format

Tags: javascript

Using javascript on Ajax call I get the date format as

```
Mon Feb 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530(India Standard Time).
```

I want to change the date format according to clients system date format using javascript.

Can anybody help me with this issue...

Comment: Please share what have you tried

Comment: What is date format you want to convert

Comment: Check out javascript's *native* Date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date it has methods for parsing and printing dates

Comment: I want the date format of the clients machine...the culture info

Comment: I am not getting the date as per my system format ..My system format date is 20-Feb-17

Comment: var value = orders[i].Date;
      var dt = new Date(parseInt(value.substring(6, value.length - 2)));
 var dtString = dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" dt.getFullYear();   @SaurabhSharma This is what I am using for now.

Comment: you can try [toLocaleDateString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toLocaleDateString.asp) to convert the date to your/clients system date format

Comment: @siam I had used this..It din work for me..

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

You can use `.toLocaleDateString()` to format date based on the client's machine.

```js
    var date=new Date();
    alert(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

---

You should really be using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

you can initialize locale using `moment.locale();` and then format it accordingly.
Follow the link for documentation

Comment: Ok ..I will check

Comment: .toLocaleDateString() gives me the format as 2/13/2017 whereas it has to be 13-Feb-17 format

Comment: Check how your system date is displayed, if it's same as what above code returns, then try changing the system locale from 'Region and Locale' in Windows and try again

Comment: Actually I dont want to change my system locale..I want the date in system date time format which I am not able to get :(

Comment: I am just asking you to give it a try if it works out for you or not

Answer (score 0):

simple... the following code should do the job :

```js
var date = new Date();
var dateString = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();

console.log(dateString);
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: @Soni you want to convert clients system date format to your system date format?

Comment: No its the other way..I have the date I want to change it to clients system date format..

Comment: See Client can change his system date format..So I dont want to hardcode the month and year format..I want to just change the date to  clients date time  format .

Comment: @Soni its not hard-coded.. its getting the date dynamically

Comment: Thanks a lot @siam  for helping me with this issue but still this code din work for me..

Comment: @Soni oh.. :/ in which format you want the date string `20/2/2017` or `20-Feb-2017`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dateObj.getTimezoneOffset()` method to get the timezone offset and then add/subtract according to the result you receive, as described here on 
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) and already answered [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
var newDate = new Date(date.getTime()+date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);

var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
var hours = date.getHours();

newDate.setHours(hours - offset);

return newDate;   
}
```

Usage:

```
var date = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(new Date(date_string_you_received));
```

Display the time based on local time

```
date.toLocaleString();
```

as answered by @Adorjan Princz

Comment: I tried using this function and I got the format as gives me the format as 2/13/2017 whereas it has to be 13-Feb-17 format

Comment: all you have to do it use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to the view you want, in your case
`moment(date).format('Do MMMM YY');`
check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsjain007/h38h0Ljf/2/) hope this solves your date format problem as well