# Convert DateTime to Local Timezone - Sugarcrm Moment js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, sugarcrm

I am trying to change a specific datetime to user/local timezone datetime. But i couldnt able to convert it. I tried all possible solutions availabe for javascript and tried moment js. It still give me `invalid date`.

My DateTime Object:

```
{date: "2017-07-14 14:23:30.000000", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC"}
```

What I am trying is to convert it to the user timezone or local timezone.

Is there any options available in Moment.js to do it?

In my SugarCRM JavaScript, I couldnt use `Date.toUTC`.

Methods I tried:

[Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)

Comment: So you are trying to convert to timezone for example `timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'` or `timeZone: 'America/Detroit'` like this?

Comment: Just converting it to `2017-07-14 19:23:30.000000` my local time is 5+ IST

Comment: Do not put an answer in the question description, instead, if significantly different from all the other answers, write your own as an answer. You may even accept it if you feel the other answers are not close enough.

Comment: done @EmileBergeron thats sound correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// input data
var myDateTime = {
    date: "2017-07-14 14:23:30.000000",
    timezone_type: 3,
    timezone: "UTC"
};

// Z in string and format in order to force UTC
var utcMoment = moment(myDateTime.date + "Z", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SZ");
// convert to time zone of sugar user
var myDate = SUGAR.App.date.UTCtoLocalTime(utcMoment);
// format output
var localDateTime = myDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Result:

```
localDateTime
"2017-07-14 16:23:30"
```

Comment: @TomPHP do you mean with .000000 or what format? :)
What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Like YYYY-MM-DD HH:SS insted of getting fullyear() like that.

Comment: I found the solution for it `moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: @TomPHP Ah nice, well done! :) I was somewhat disappointed/surprised by stock javascript not having a .format() function, so good to know that moment() helps out with that.

Comment: You should never parse strings with the built in Date parser, `new Date("2017-07-14 14:23:30.000000")`  returns an invalid date in Safari.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to put the Z at the end: `myDateTime.date + 'Z'` as that's where most would expect it to be (and adjust the parse format accordingly).

Comment: Sure, why not :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution with the [help of @jay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45143543/1218980), did a few modifications and made it work for me.

```
var myDateTime = {
    date: "2017-07-14 14:23:30.000000", 
    timezone_type: 3, 
    timezone: "UTC"
};
var myDate = SUGAR.App.date.UTCtoLocalTime(new Date(myDateTime.date));
// 2017-07-14 12:20:26
var resultDate = moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// Mon, Jul 17, 2017 10:40 AM 
var resultformat = moment(myDate).format('llll');
```

Comment: `new Date("2017-07-14 14:23:30.000000")`  returns an invalid date in Safari. If you're using moment.js, you should parse the string properly.

Comment: could you post ur answer if it workd for u in safari.

Comment: My answer would be very much the same as Jay's answer.