# Formating time output from Google calendar API

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar, google-calendar-api

I found this code at Google Quickstart calendar API and I have been trying to format the time output but I'm not succeeding.

I tried changing time zones and reading documentation from Android developers but I didn't manage to fix it.

I'm trying to get something like

> 2017-07-29 16:00:00

But I'm getting

> 2017-07-29T14:00:00.000Z

Also time zone is different it should be +2.

```
    private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();

        for (Event event : items) {
            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
            if (start == null) {
                start = event.getStart().getDate();
            }
            eventStrings.add(
                    String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
        }
        return eventStrings;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar API's [default timezone](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) is UTC (which is what you're seeing), formatted according to  [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

> The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to
> RFC3339). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is
> explicitly specified in timeZone.

Try using [toTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString) to convert it to human-readable format. You can also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript) for other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getFormattedDate(Date date)
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+05:30");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
        return df.format(date);
    }
```