# Posting DateTime from Angular to Asp Core gets 3 hours late

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm posting from  Angular 6 to Asp Core api,object has one field Date type ,before posting it is shown in console:

```
Mon Jul 16 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
```

but in Asp Core api is shown as `{15/07/2018 9:00:00 PM}`, 3 hours late and one day off,how to fix that?

thanks

Comment: Its because in the AspNet Core API it converts the time to UTC time, so you need to convert it back to (Eastern European Summer Time)

Comment: and how I can do that?

Comment: What really happens is that JSON date encoding - which angular `HttpClient` module makes use when it has to make a POST request - transforms a date to UTC date.

Comment: in your asp core api add the time your time zone is ahead of the UTC, it should work fine. Or just use UTC everywhere which is preferred.

Comment: @mrapi an easy way to do it would be to use the JavaScript library moment, there’s a function that converts utc time to your local time

Comment: Hi,I've added in controller,but not working:  ob.DATA = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(ob.DATA, 
     TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));

Comment: @Roopesh how to use UTC everywhere?

Comment: your asp.net core is already receiving time in utc format. when you're getting data back to the front end, like @SmokeyDawson said use javascript methods to convert utc to your local time.

Comment: I've used this function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441370/3492996

Comment: If you check [this](https://savvytime.com/converter/eest-to-utc) website and input 16 July midnight EEST, you can see the UTC for that date is 15 July, 9pm. So as other users have commented, you can convert the source date to UTC using awesome library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/) or convert the date back to EEST in your backend using code such as `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(yourTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));`