# Convert UTC time to local time in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to convert this utc format date to india date and time format in angular

```
2019-02-18T17:31:19-05:00
```

I expect in this format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM(eg: 02/19/2019 04:01 AM). Can anyone please suggest me how to do it..

Comment: Is this to be shown on your component.html? Or component.ts?

Comment: check https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it in vanilla JavaScript would be to make use of [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), and to convert it to the Indian timezone by setting it as the `timeZone` property.

```
new Date('2019-02-18T17:31:19-05:00').toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"});
```

```js
console.log(new Date('2019-02-18T17:31:19-05:00').toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Formats a date value according to locale rules.

`{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}`

Sourxe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 2):

in ts

```
import {utc} from 'moment';
utc = utc;
```

in html

```
{{ utc("2019-02-18T17:31:19-05:00").local().format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use a locale_id in your module all date pipes should adhere to that locale
https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID

Answer (score 0):

UTC dates should have 'Z' appended to it. E.g. `2019-02-18T17:31:00Z`.

Secondly, convert the date string to a Date object by using `Date.parse()`

Then use date filter to display the date `<span> {{ dateStr | date }}</span>`

**Check below
JS -**

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dateStr = Date.parse('2019-02-18T17:31:00Z');
});
```

**HTML -**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{ dateStr | date }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use a awesome library for date and time related manipulation.

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

In your case you can try out the following

```
moment.tz('2019-02-18T17:31:19-05:00', 'Asia/Kolkata').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a');
```

This will return you the date in the desired format. Let me know if any further explanation is required for this.