# Convert UTC time to Browser's local time in angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

From the server I am getting a `DateTime` in this format: `2019-07-11T05:33:53.45` and it is in UTC time.

I want to convert it to the current user’s browser time using JavaScript in the format like `11th July 2019 11:03 AM` which is `UTC+0530` for Indian time for given time(2019-07-11T05:33:53.45).

I have tried `Intl.DateTimeFormat` and also other JavaScript date time functions eg. `toLocaleString`. But I am getting the time in UTC format only. When I get the time as what I want UTC+0530 is also attached, which I don't want.

```
let d = new Date(date_from_server);
let options= { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
                    hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
                    hour12: false };                    
let ddmmmyy= new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', options).format(d);
```

This is one of the solution I tried. I have tried other methods also, but didn't succeed.
eg. let ddmmmyy = d.toLocaleString();

I want the time as per User's current browser timezone and in the specified format(11th July 2019 11:03 AM IST).

How can I achieve it? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `T` in the date string and also append `UTC`.
Then you need to remove `GMT` and anything after that in the result:

```js
var dateString = "2019-07-11T05:33:53.45".replace('T', ' ') + " UTC"; // or + "Z" instead of + " UTC";
var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
var localDateString = dateObj.toString().replace(/GMT.*/g,"");
console.log(localDateString);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works perfectly in Chrome. But it is not working in IE11 and Firefox. Is there any solution to make it work in other browsers also?

Comment: @Chaits14: Appending `"Z"`  instead of `" UTC"` should do the trick. `Z` stands for `Zulu` and comes from the military tradion of using the phonetic alphabet. The letter `Z` is in the phonetical alphabet `Zulu`. Why `Z`? Each time zone is expressed as a certain number of hours `ahead of UTC` or `behind UTC`? (For example, UTC -5 is Eastern Standard Time.) The letter `Z` refers to the Greenwich time zone, which is zero hours (UTC + 0).

Comment: Appending "Z" to the server time fixed my problem. It is working in all the browsers now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date('2019-08-14 17:00:34 UTC');
date.toString(); // outputs "Wed Aug 14 2019 13:00:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
```