# How to convert a Date object to output only hh:mm am/pm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time

I am attempting to convert the following into a 12 hour am/pm format.

Currently I am recieving the Day, Month, Year and timezone.

*Fixed by adding .toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3")*

```
<div id="time1"></div>
<div id="time2"></div>
```

```
var date = new Date('08/16/2019 12:00:00 PM UTC').toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3")
document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = date;

var date = new Date('08/16/2019 6:00:00 am UTC').toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3")
document.getElementById("time2").innerHTML = date;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Updated to reflect the change

Comment: So, `"12pm"` the exact input you need converted, and that should be interpreted as 12:00 PM on the current UTC date?  Have you tried anything to solve *that* yet?  And for output, what are you looking for there?  A `Date` object? A string in a specific format?  Also, your comment about "does not work in the CDN I am using" is very unclear.  There is no requirement to use a CDN to use a library like Moment, and if you are using jQuery then you are using libraries already.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Updated to reflect your questions. The CDN = Wordpress seems to be conflicting with Moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you have to do is use the Date() default javascript function and make sure you append the UTC timezone:

```
var date = new Date('08/16/2019 7:00:00 PM UTC')

date.toString=() //will then print out the timezone adjusted time

"Fri Aug 16 2019 22:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)"
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei, how would I then convert date.toString to display without dd/mm/yyyy, in 12 hour am/pm, without (timezone)?

Answer (score 0):

There are many built in javascript methods to handle converting date objects. This example will look to the browser to determine date format and time.

```
let time = Date.now();
time.toLocaleDateString();
```