# How to display the date and time that is in the country in the React Date Picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

The server returns me the date of example 2019-07-30, 23:59
I put it in the `selected` property, 23:59 is displayed in input. I live in Poland. How to change to display 23:00?
 I use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

```
 <DatePicker
      selected = {} 
      onChange this.props.handleChangeDateTask = {}
      showTimeSelect
      timeformat = "HH: mm"
      timeIntervals = {15}
      dateFormat = "dd / MM / yyyy HH: mm"
      timeCaption = "time"
    />
```

Comment: Why can't you subtract an hour from the time in the code?

Comment: `"2019-07-30, 23:59".slice(0, -2) + "00"` before setting `selected`?

Comment: use moment to add location support - https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Barsban I would prefer to set it depending on the location

Comment: @Patricia I would prefer to set it depending on the location

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting `utc` time from the server,

you can use `new Date('2019-07-30 23:59 UTC')` (just append 'UTC' to your date) as the `selected` in `<DatePicker/>`,

if you are getting the time in another timezone you will have to use moment to convert it to your timezone

Comment: And if I kept date from server and it is  assign to a variable `date`,  how can I add UTC?

Comment: are you creating a `javascript` `Date` object from the server date? if not i should be coming to you as a string right? If its a string you can just concatenate "UTC" to it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server is sending utc time you can covert that to local time

```
var date = new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');
date.toString() // "Wed Jun 29 2011 09:52:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

[Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)

Use this logic to show correct local time.