# How to convert UTC time to local time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django-templates, datetime-format

My backend is in Django. I used Django's auto_now_add feature on the model to add the current time when that model was created. For example, I am passing this value to the function:  `2019-10-08 09:16:20.666754+00:00`.
How to convert this in local time in Javascript? I have not coded JS. So the line's a bit blurry for me.

I tried the following method:

```
function localize_time(date) {
    date = new Date(date);
    date = date.toString();
}
```

Then I saw another SO post to add "UTC", that's not working either. when I am calling a said function from Django's template, it's showing following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

It's on that function.

In Django's template, I am calling the function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    localize_time({{ user.created_on | safe}});
</script>
```

If I don't add safe, then the error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)

Comment: @RamblinRose, No. Read the post entirely before marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: Hmm...I removed the duplicate flag right after I created it, I don't understand why it's here.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the Django's time in milliseconds using `datetime.timestamp` method and rest of things worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add UTC at the end of your date string.

```
const date = new Date('2019-10-08 09:16:20.666754+00:00 UTC');
alert(date.toString())
```

Comment: can you please add the value that you're passing to the date function?

Comment: 2019-10-08 09:16:20.666754+00:00

Comment: try this please - i've checked it and it works like magic.

let date = new Date('2019-10-08 09:16:20.666754+00:00 UTC');