# Convert given time to local system time without using timezone function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs

```
var aestTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Brisbane"});
aestTime = new Date(aestTime);
console.log('AEST time: '+aestTime.toLocaleString())

var asiaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Shanghai"});
asiaTime = new Date(asiaTime);
console.log('Asia time: '+asiaTime.toLocaleString())

var usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
 usaTime = new Date(usaTime);
 console.log('USA time: '+usaTime.toLocaleString())
```

This is the output from running the above code:

```
AEST time: 11/12/2019, 3:39:31 PM
test.html:36 Asia time: 11/12/2019, 1:39:31 PM
test.html:40 USA time: 11/12/2019, 12:39:31 AM
```

Without giving timezone I want the receive the same output, how do I do that?

```
var aestTime =  

output :- 11/12/2019 3:39:31 PM  

var asiaTime =

 output:- 11/12/2019, 1:39:31 PM 

var usaTime = 

 11/12/2019, 12:39:31 AM
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: how to get a DateTime based on country Without mentioning timezone?

Comment: getting date in this format 2018-10-10 15:54:29.
 even i too don't know that's why i had posted..but my requirement should be without mentioning timezone we should get current local system time

Answer (score 0):

You can try momentjs. Refer to https://momentjs.com/docs/

The code can be

```
const moment = require('moment');
const now = moment();
console.log(now.format('L LTS'));
```

This will give the current local system time without mentioning the timezone.

The result will be

> 11/12/2019 12:49:46 PM

Comment: i have time in this format "2019-11-12 05:59:27" this time should be converted to local system user may be from Usa or England or any country but that time should be converted to user local system time

Answer (score 0):

let utcTime = "2019-12-27 20:30:00";
let local = moment.utc(utcTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A').local().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A");

output:-

2019-12-28 02:00:00 AM