# i want to change my date ant time according to client system timezone

Tags: javascript, telerik-grid

in my database one column has `utcdatetime` value and i want show that **date time** in the timezone of the country.

this is my database value: **2020-02-25 11:12:28 PM** and i want output a value for example **us system**: 
**2020-02-25 1:12:28 PM** approximately because **India is 10 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Washington, DC, USA**

i tried with the code below:

```
 function GridCreated(sender, args) {
            var masterTable = $find("<%= dgAdminErrorLog.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
        var items = masterTable.get_dataItems();

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var date = masterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(items[i], "ErrorDateTimeUtc").innerHTML;
             // conver the date and set it back to the cell.
            var d = new Date();
            var systimezone = d.getTimezone();
            var indiaTime = date.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone});
           masterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(items[i], "ErrorDateTimeUtc").innerHTML = indiaTime.toLocaleString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6525538/1115360) give you any useful ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
var usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/New_York"
});
usaTime = new Date(usaTime);
console.log("USA time: " + usaTime.toLocaleString());
```