# How to convert datetime to local time in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

While saving the data I want the time to be displayed in users local time as of now it is saving in utc.

Code :

```
NarrativeContentLastModifiedOn = valuation.NarrativeContentLastModifiedOn;
```

So how do I convert this date time to user's local datetime.

Comment: Local `DateTime` values only make sense on desktop. For a web server use `DateTimeOffset`. You can get the users timezone via javascript, or let the user store their preference somewhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time