# Convert datetime to user's time

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix, timezone, dayjs

I am using dayjs and trying to achieve a datetime conversion depending on the user's locale.

Example;

The data I have is 15 April 2024 America/Toronto 16:00. I want to convert this to user's timezone - i.e Australia/Sydney or Europe/Paris or wherever they are. Also, the data I get won't be only from America/Toronto, it could be a different timezone, so I need to make that dynamic, too.

I thought unix timestamp has the information of timezone(silly me) so I was trying by that conversion only to realise it didn't work because unix is utc based. I do not want to use momentjs for this and thinking we should be able to do this either by dayjs or vanilla js.

Comment: what's your input data exactly a string, Date object or something else?

Comment: Date, time and timezone fields. This is the console.log with those info: 15/04/2024 16:00:00 America/Toronto

Comment: toLocaleString() possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70644555/how-to-get-date-as-the-local-date. You can create a date knowing its locale, and "parts" (day, months, year etc.) then you can convert it to UTC. From there on it's an easy task to convert to whatever locale you want.

Comment: you mention `unix timestamp`, and since that is the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970 0:00 UTC .... and javascript dates are the number of milliseconds since the exact same time ... therefore, to convert, multiply by 1000 and you're done. `new Date(1701300787665)` for example will output in the end users timezone - there's no hoops to jump through

Comment: @user1514042—in the context of *toLocaleString* the word "locale" means "language" (a misnomer in ECMAScript originating with ECMA-402 I think and cheerfully propagated by libraries and various javascript resources). It's just a serendipitous side effect that *toLocaleString* can also be used to set the timezone for a date and time formatted according to common use in a particular language. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the plugin [`timezone`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/timezone) ([GitHub current commit permalink](https://github.com/dayjs/dayjs-website/blob/8e838c9d5985e675260e99516b873ec5ca196b65/docs/plugin/timezone.md)) and the section on [formatting](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) ([permalink](https://github.com/dayjs/dayjs-website/blob/8e838c9d5985e675260e99516b873ec5ca196b65/docs/display/format.md)). Here's a runnable snippet to demonstrate:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.10/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.10/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.10/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  // Imported as UMD modules in this demo:
  const {
    dayjs,
    dayjs_plugin_timezone: timezone,
    dayjs_plugin_utc: utc,
  } = window;

  dayjs.extend(utc);
  dayjs.extend(timezone);

  const dSource = dayjs.tz("2024-04-15 16:00", "America/Toronto"); // in original tz
  const localTimeZone = dayjs.tz.guess();
  const dLocal = dSource.tz(localTimeZone); // in local tz

  const formatStr = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
  const formatted = `${dLocal.format(formatStr)} ${localTimeZone}`;

  const tzSydney = "Australia/Sydney";
  const formattedSydney = `${dSource.tz(tzSydney).format(formatStr)} ${tzSydney}`;

  console.log("formatted =", formatted) // formatted using your host environment's local time zone
  console.log("formattedSydney =", formattedSydney) // "2024-04-16 06:00:00 Australia/Sydney"
</script>
```