# How to convert UTC to local date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, utc

I want to convert `2022-01-15T12:22:24.0078237` into `Sat Jan 15 2022 23:24:18 GMT+1100`. The answers in [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time) say that the `Date` constructor should convert from UTC to local date, but clearly this isn't working here. What can I do to convert the UTC date into the local client date?

```
new Date("2022-01-15T12:22:24.0078237")
> Sat Jan 15 2022 12:22:24 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
new Date()
> Sat Jan 15 2022 23:24:18 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: Isn't your question answered here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time

Comment: @Eduard—the accepted answer there is to add "UTC", which is not a good idea as explained in answers to [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'Z' to the date string, like this:

```
const dateString = "2022-01-15T12:22:24.0078237";
const localDate = new Date(dateString + "Z");
```

Comment: please don't forget to mark answers as correct when they are correct :)