# Check midnight in a specific time zone node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone

I have user's timezone, let say

> timeZone: 'America/New_York'

I want to perform some tasks at midnight according to the user's timezone. How can I check if the midnight has arrived in this timezone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)

Answer (score 3):

Last midnight in a specific timezone:

```
new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York', timeZoneName: 'short' } ))
```

Database friendly UTC time of last midnight in a specific timezone

```
new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York', timeZoneName: 'short' } )).toISOString()
```

Note: understand 'last midnight' as today-in-zone midnight

Explanation:

- `new Date()` is current time (whatever the zone - time object)
- `.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York', timeZoneName: 'short' } )` displays the current date (no time, so midnight) in the specified zone (string of time with zone ref)
- `new Date(<above midnight time in zone>)` parse the midnight time in zone and display corresponding current timezone time (time object)
- `.toISOString()` display above at UTC reference (ISO datetime string)