# How to convert UTC time to local

Tags: javascript

I have a string representation of UTC time, such as:

```
var dateTimeStringUTC = '2024-01-05T10:00:00Z';
```

I want to convert this to Eastern Time, **but keep the time as 10:00 am**.

```
var dateTimeUTC = new Date(dateTimeStringUTC); // this gets converted to: Fri Jan 05 2024 05:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

How can accomplish this using vanilla javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)

Comment: Would dateTimeUTC.toLocaleTimeString() fix your problem if not could you provide what you want it to return. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

Comment: The answer provided works, but you should actually fix whatever is handing you the wrong time.

Comment: remove the `Z` from the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the time difference. Here's how you can do it using vanilla JavaScript:

```js
var d = new Date('2024-01-05T10:00:00Z');
var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset(); // offset in minutes
d.setTime(d.getTime() + offset *60*1000);
console.log(d.toString()); // logs the date and time as 10:00 AM Eastern Time
```

This code will convert the date/time into the current user's timezone. Basically it will treat the input date as being in the timezone of the user.