# How do I append the user's timezone to a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I found [some code here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3833699/184108) that does exactly what I want, which is to take a GMT time string and convert it to the local time on the user's browser. Awesome.

However, I'm stuck on what should be a very small thing. When I display the time, I want the user's current local timezone to display along with the time. The goal is to output a string that looks something like:

```
2014/02/19 15:12 (PST)
```

I've looked at [the parameters for the Javascript Date() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), but, unless I'm blind, I don't see one that outputs the user's timezone. There's `getTimezoneOffset()`, which returns a number, but not the code for the timezone.

I've got all the rest of the time displaying fine, except for that last part where I want it to say `PST` (or `GMT` or `JST` or wherever the user is). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Without commenting on the rest of the question, [w3schools is a bad resource](http://www.w3fools.com); I'd suggest [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: @Daedalus, noted. I've changed the link to use MDN instead. I also took a look at the MDN page to see if there was any difference that revealed a lead on how to answer my question, but I didn't see anything that had an impact.

Comment: i found something that might help you. http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

Comment: @scarecrow, thank you for that. However, I really do need to get the 3 letter timezone code because of space restrictions. As far as I can tell, the code you linked to provides longer strings, for example `Asia/Tokyo` or`Germany/Berlin`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done creating a date and then performing some operations on it. If you take a look at format in which newly created Date object is created it is e.g. like:

```
Wed Feb 19 2014 07:29:26 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Now you may simply take the whole name like:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var userTmzn = myDate.substring(myDate.lastIndexOf('(')+1).replace(')','').trim()
```

and this should give you this in userTmzn

```
Central European Standard Time
```

Now to make it neat and have an abbreviation you may try some more operations:

```
// Take the part with timezone name and strip it from trailing ')'
var fullName = myDate.split("(")[1].replace(")","");

 // Split into words
var words = fullName.split(" ");

// Take just first letters
var timezoneCode = "";
for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    timezoneCode += words[i].charAt(0);
}
```

That should give you (following the same example) this in timezoneCode variable:

```
CEST
```

This is highly custom, not a ready solution. You should verify in the code that default date's toString() returns date in TIME FORMAT, you should test on various browsers, etc. This is just a clue.